# Does setting setNumberRows de-allocate the unneeded rows?

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos, wkinterfacetable

I'm using a `WKInterfaceTable` on WatchOS.

If for example the table already has **5 rows**,

and I

`.setNumberOfRows(2, withRowType: "rows")` so that it now only has **2 rows**,

does that mean that the 3 rows that are no longer visible are **deallocated**

(or do I have to run `apptTable.removeRows` to de-allocate)?

Thanks

Comment: I'm asking because https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacetable/1615832-setnumberofrows?language=objc is not very explicit about this point.

Comment: @DávidPásztor if you're 100% certain, just post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you call `.setNumberOfRows`, the `WKInterfaceTable` will be updated, so yes, the extra 3 rows in your example will be removed. There's no need to manually call removeRows.

This is explicitly stated [in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacetable/1615832-setnumberofrows) as well:

> Use this method when you want to populate a table with rows that are
>   all of the same type. This method **removes any existing rows** from the
>   table and configures a new set of rows based on the information in the
>   numberOfRows and rowType parameters.